# Recyclerview: Hiding Items without removing them from the ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I've been searching for that for quite a while and haven't found a proper answer:

Is there a way to remove an Item from a RecyclerView without removing it from the underlying ArrayList?
I want to add a functionality, to temporarily hide Items from the List, when a certain condition is true. I still need those items back later, but managing 2 separate ArrayList seems overly complicated.
If I set the Visibility of the Item inside the Adapter to `gone`, I have a visible gap where the item was, so that is not a solution.

Is there any way by which I can avoid managing 2 separate ArrayLists?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of what the RecyclerView looks like when you set the item visibility to `GONE`?

Comment: Please post your adapter code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll have to actually remove from the data model. Otherwise, you'll either end up with blank rows, as you say, or when you scroll, the "hidden" recycled elements will get jumbled up.

Just because you remove from the the Arraylist doesn't mean you can't add another list to (temporarily) store the items that were removed.

For example, define this in the adapter

```
private List<Item> removed = new ArrayList<>();

public void remove(int position) {
    removed.add(items.get(position));
    items.remove(position);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

If you need better functionality about which items you have removed, a Hashmap may be better.

Comment: or `removed.add(items.remove(position));`

Answer (score 0):

you have an ArrayList of object type
You have a model/pojo class of Object type

while iterating  JsonData from JsonResponse just pass boolean value true/false in object type Model class. The data you want to show make it true else false, later you can set the 'false value to true' to your Model class.

Hope this will work.

Comment: I think the question is about hiding entire rows, not single views.

Comment: Do adapter layout(row_item) maping in activity and set the adapter in recyclerview/Listview before loading data from server. After getting data don't do 'adapter.notifyDataSetChanged' so your listview will be blank/hide. Whenever you want view to be shown just do notifyDataSetChanged.

Comment: Why wouldn't you notify the adapter after getting data? Also, still not sure row that prevents a View from being inflated into a row

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using `getApplicationContext()` instead of `getContext` or `this`